# Lazy property with UIView subclass

Tags: ios, swift, type-inference, lazy-initialization

I want to add `UIView` subclass property with lazy initialization, for example:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {}

class Controller: UIViewController {

    lazy var myView = MyView()
}
```

But I have an error:

> Cannot convert values type 'UIView' to specified type 'MyView'
>   I can fix the error with type of property:

```
lazy var myView: MyView = MyView()
```

or change initialization to:

```
let myView = MyView()
```

but why Swift cannot inference the type?

Comment: Also works if I call one of the UIView initializers `lazy var myView = MyView(frame: .zero)`. The original question still remains...

Comment: @kennytm, good remark, thanks!

Comment: Not sure why, but you need to call a designated initializer to make it works correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing is providing a type if you are an initialized to a variable marked lazy.

```
  lazy var myView:MyView = MyView()
```

Comment: Why? Show me proofs!

Comment: when you use lazy  the actual value is created by evaluation so you need to declare its data type up front.You can check it over https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-lazy-variables

Comment: but why I can commit type in this case: `lazy var myView = UIView()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue but with custom class. And did not found any issues.

One thing to be noted is, when the lazy property had no customisations (the `defaultValue` in sample) compiler did not asked me to provide the explicit type.
But
For the property with customisation (`redView`), I had to provide the explicit type. 
If I did not provide explicit type here is what I got.

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to
>   disambiguate

And this says clearly enough, that the closure's return type cannot be inferred. Its seems obvious because the closure we are using has no explicit return type.

[image]

So I tried to supply a closure with explicit type and I was expecting now that now I would not need to provide the explicit type for the `redView` `lazy` property. And as expected, it worked without supplying the type for the lazy property.

[image]

Comment: You're talking about closures. But I used only subclass with default initialization.

Answer (score 0):

if you provide init for MyView, then it will be ok.but why? I spent hours to figure out, the result is , waiting for the master to answer.

```
class MyView: UIView {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, also works with [kennytm example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639651/lazy-property-with-uiview-subclass?noredirect=1#comment72406840_42639651)